# Mobile device by measurement protocol GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, measurement-protocol

as you know, measurement protocol in GA4 is very limited. i have problem with tracking events from mobile devices in measurement protocol - at my reports there is only 'desktop'. I saw many suggestions of solution this problem (like using [custom definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76946907/how-to-set-device-information-when-passing-an-event-to-ga4-via-measurement-proto)) but it it looks inappropriate. If you had same problem at your project and solve it please give me know.

also I found this [answer](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/238057335) from Google Analytics API team but there is also no solution

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution of this problem. I added some custom parameters on measurement protocol request, checked it at 'Event builder' by Google and then added some custom parameters by 'event' on GA4.